# Getting error "Could not find preset 'react-server' relative to directory ..."

Tags: node.js, reactjs, svg, npm, react-server

Full error message:

> ../assets/around/TCircle.svg
>   Module build failed: Error: Couldn't find preset "react-server" relative to directory "/Users/admin/Documents"
>       at Array.map (native)

I'm getting the error above over and over, but there's no single mention of react-server in the whole project's directory.

What I'm trying to accomplish is to link assets directory as an `npm` dependency, and access them throughout the project.

Also (this may sound silly) - but it works perfectly on others' machines.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this same issue. In my case, there was a `.babelrc` file in the *parent* directory that included the `react-server` preset. Deleting the `.babelrc` file in the parent directory solved the problem.

This is the [expected lookup behavior](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/babelrc#lookup-behavior) according to Babel's docs.